# SQLite query on multiple tables with reference Id table

Tags: android, sqlite

I need help by a little SQLite problem, in my App a user can add some todos and connect this todos with contacts , but a contact have multiple connections for multiple todos. My question is how must look my query if I want all contacts for a specific todo ?

Todos

```
todoId  todoTitle 
0        do some
1        do some
```

Contacts

```
contactId contactName
299             Stan
231             Jeff
```

ReferenceIds

```
 contactId  todoId
  299         0
  299         1
  231         0
```

Comment: please mark some query as answer if it was helpful

Comment: Oh sorry jeah it solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have such a many-to-many relationship, you can get all contacts for a specified todo ID with a query like this one:

```
SELECT contactId, contactName
FROM contacts
JOIN referenceIds ON referenceIds.contactId = contacts.contactId
WHERE todoId = ID
```

Note that the above query didn't select any columns from the `todos` table. If you also want columns from that table, you need a second join like so:

```
SELECT contactId, contactName, todoTitle
FROM contacts
JOIN referenceIds ON referenceIds.contactId = contacts.contactId
JOIN todos ON todos.todoId = referenceIds.todoId
WHERE todoId = ID
```

Comment: second join is redundant todoid for search already joined from referenceIds table

Comment: @PogonetsAnton That's true, unless you also intend to select anything from todos table in this query (I'm used to selecting columns from both tables when I make these kinds of queries). I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if you want one-to-many relation you don't need relations table. It is necessary for many-to-many. If 1 contact have many todos and each todo have one contact - just add contactId to todos table. In this case you can simply select from `Todos` table by contactId

In your case you should make query joins

```
select distinct c.* 
from Contacts as c
inner join ReferenceIds as r on c.contactId = r.contactId
where todoId = ?
```

Comment: My first solutiom was a todoId column in my contacts table,  do you think your way its a good choice then contacts can have multiple todos and todos can have multiple contacts ?

Comment: "todoid in contacts table" is one todo to many contacts. which kind of relation you want?

Comment: In my tododetailview there are one todo and many contacts and then I have a listview with contacts and in this Detailview many todos. And one contact can have multiple todo eg. Stan can have todo A, todoB and todoD but Jeff have only todo B ... sorry for my bad english